# How can I load video into an app from backend?

Tags: android, iframe, webview

My problem is how to a show video from the admin backend into my android app. When I and adding the iframe from [TinyMCE Editor](https://www.tinymce.com/), it looks like this:

[image: image1]

But in my android app I get this:

[image: image2]

I cannot understand what exactly is happening and I'm sharing you a section of my code of what I'm doing in the fragment.

```
if (item.getContent().length() != 0) {

        mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

        mWebView.getSettings().setMinimumFontSize(14);

        String htmlContent = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>"
                           + "<head>"
                           + "<meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />"
                           + "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\"/>"
                           + "<style type=\"text/css\">body{color: #525252;} img {max-width: 100%; height: auto}</style>"
                           + "</head>"
                           + item.getContent()
                           + "";

        mWebView.loadData(htmlContent,  "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");


    } else {

        mWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if (item.getImgUrl().length() > 0) {

        imageLoader.get(item.getImgUrl(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(mItemImg, R.drawable.img_loading, R.drawable.img_loading));
        mItemImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mItemImgSeparatorLine.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else {

        mItemImg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mItemImgSeparatorLine.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    mPostTopSeparatorLine.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mPostMessage.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    if (item.getAllowComments() == 0 && App.getInstance().getId() != 0) {

        mPostTopSeparatorLine.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mPostMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        mPostMessage.setText(getString(R.string.msg_comments_disabled));
    }

    if (App.getInstance().getId() == 0) {

        mPostTopSeparatorLine.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mPostMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        mPostMessage.setText(getString(R.string.msg_auth_prompt_comment));
    }
}
```

For my Android App I'm working with a WebView as you can see in the above code. Do you have any idea why is it not working as expected? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to load an `iFrame` in `WebView`. To do so, use first create a string with the HTML.

```
String html = "<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\"  src=\"your_src\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
```

Now call `loadData`.

```
mWebview.loadData(html, "text/html", null);
```